# command output give object string how to convert it to json using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

a command gives the following output which is arranged in an object, how to convert it to json using jq?

```
{\n  currentBlock: 4769045,\n  highestBlock: 7063981,\n  knownStates: 15306625,\n  pulledStates: 15306625,\n  startingBlock: 0\n}
```

N.B the output isn't json; it contains `\n` strings.

i used the following to convert it

```
echo "$output" | jq -R -s -c 'split("\n")'
```

but the output wasn't as i expect it

["{","  currentBlock: 4787477,","  highestBlock: 7063981,","  knownStates: 15306625,","  pulledStates: 15306625,","  startingBlock: 0","}",""]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue here is that the quasi-JSON contains literal "\n" strings, then you could perhaps remove them using `sed 's/\\n//g'`:

```
$ output='{\n currentBlock: 4769045,\n highestBlock: 7063981,\n knownStates: 15306625,\n pulledStates: 15306625,\n startingBlock: 0\n}'

$ jq -n -f <(sed 's/\\n//g' <<< "$output")
```

Another possibility might be to use `printf`, e.g.

```
$ printf "$output" "" | hjson -j
```

Both yield valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, the "output" as originally shown is a valid jq program, so to convert it to JSON, you could simply provide it to the jq processor as a program, e.g.:

```
jq -n '{ currentBlock: 4479441, highestBlock: 7063981, knownStates: 15306625, pulledStates: 15306625, startingBlock: 0 }'
```

### Output

```
{
  "currentBlock": 4479441,
  "highestBlock": 7063981,
  "knownStates": 15306625,
  "pulledStates": 15306625,
  "startingBlock": 0
}
```

#### Using the -f option

If the quasi-JSON is in a file, say data.txt, then you could simply run:

```
jq -n -f data.txt
```

#### Caveats

This approach will only work if the text happens to be valid as a jq program.  In particular, it won't work if any of the keys is an unquoted jq keyword, or does not match the regex:

```
^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*$
```

Comment: jq -n '{\n  currentBlock: 4769045,\n  highestBlock: 7063981,\n  knownStates: 15306625,\n  pulledStates: 15306625,\n  startingBlock: 0\n}'

Comment: The Q as shown by SO does not mention anything about newlines or '\n` strings.  Please clarify the Q.

Comment: Line breaks would not cause problems, but literal `"\n"` strings would.  Please see the separate answer about handling such strings.

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution would be to use a tool such as [hjson](/questions/tagged/hjson):

```
$ echo '{ currentBlock: 4479441, highestBlock: 7063981, knownStates: 15306625, pulledStates: 15306625, startingBlock: 0 }' |
    hjson -j
{
  "currentBlock": 4479441,
  "highestBlock": 7063981,
  "knownStates": 15306625,
  "pulledStates": 15306625,
  "startingBlock": 0
}
```